# Modifying Facebook share content with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I've been successfully using the [Sharrre](http://sharrre.com) plugin to add a Facebook share button to a page but I now need to change the title and description of the shared link.

I believe this was possible in the past before Facebook updated sharer.php, with the new version no longer accepting parameters for title, etc.
I can change the og:title attribute content via JavaScript but when Facebook requests the page these changes are (obviously) not present.

How are sites like Buzzfeed accomplishing this with their quizzes, where the outcome is shared?

Answer (score 1):

You need to detect the Facebook scraper server side, they use unique User Agent string.

I use this one

```
preg_match('/facebookexternalhit/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
```

Based on this, change og:title and og:description, when FB scrapes your website it will see changed params.

Comment: Thanks Artek, any suggestions on how to detect what "page" Facebook is looking for, so I can serve different content accordingly?  E.g. an ID on the querystring?

And is there a way to force FB not to cache the page?

Comment: Facebook caches by URL - so you always know what page it tries to cache when you render it. 
You can force FB to renew it's cache by sending POST request to https://graph.facebook.com
Example CURL command:
`curl -X POST -F "id=<insert url here>" -F "scrape=true" "https://graph.facebook.com"`
Sorry for the late response!